# SpriteKit SKScene add AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer CALayer as background not working

Tags: ios7, core-animation, sprite-kit

I'm attempting to add the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer CALayer as the background to my SKScene. I can add the CALayer to the scene, but no matter what attempts at ordering the CALayer is always the top most object.

In the didMoveToView I have the function:

```
- (void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    [self addVideo];

}
```

Which calls the addVideo function:

```
-(void) addVideo {

AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:nil];

[captureSession addInput:videoIn];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *avLayer =
[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
avLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

CGSize landscapeSize;
landscapeSize.width = self.view.bounds.size.height;
landscapeSize.height = self.view.bounds.size.width;


CGRect landscapeRect;
landscapeRect.size = landscapeSize;
landscapeRect.origin = self.view.bounds.origin;

avLayer.frame = landscapeRect;

if(avLayer.connection.supportsVideoOrientation)
{
    avLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

[self.scene.view.layer insertSublayer:avLayer atIndex:0];
[self.scene.view.layer setNeedsLayout];


[captureSession startRunning];
```

}

I've attempted multiple ways to get that AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer CALayer as the background. Everytime a node is added to the scene it is above this CALayer, any advice?

Attempted the following function:

```
- (void) sendSublayerToBack:(CALayer *)layer
{
   [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
}
```

But still not working....

Comment: Did you solve this Halford?

Comment: @vburojevic sorry for the late response, did not resolve this lmk if you have

Comment: @Halford How did you solve this ? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't present the layer in the SKView layer - create another UIView and position it in the view hierarchy so it is behind the SKView. Then add the video layer to that UIView.

You will have to make the SKView transparent, though here I'm not sure if this works - if at all it works like it does for cocos2d: set the opaque property to NO and change the backgroundColor property to nil (if not already nil). This should make the SKView transparent.

If none of this works maybe you can find a workaround using SKVideoNode instead.

Comment: it seems then that I will have to go with an SKVideoNode, but how do I get the live camera video feed like AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer supplies. SKVideoNode requires an AVPlayer or video file NSURL, how would you go about hooking that up to a video file in my Documents directory for example. I tried AVPlayer but you need to stop AVCaptureSession in order to get the video, and that does not satisfy the requirements. Needs to behave like AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps present a regular UIKit storyboard for the video preview, and when that part is done return to the sprite kit view controller

Comment: apologize if my initial code was not clear enough, the video is intended to be a background to the SKScene, so the SKNodes and gameplay will be on top of the camera video feed. Is there anyway to connect AVPlayer to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? Or to have AVPlayer set to some live camera feed?

Comment: No idea, but if this is an "augmented reality" app you will want to use UIImagePickerController instead. Here's the setup for a cocos2d app: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone

Comment: unfortunately SKView cannot be transparent, it's a current limitation.